# Why the disassembler plugin doesn't work in this case?

Tags: java, assembly, jvm, jit, disassembly

I'm trying to disassemble below Test class using this command:

`java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:CompileCommand=print,*Test.main Test > log.txt`

---

**Test class** :

```
public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("loading Test");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aze a = new Aze(1,2,3);
        Baz b = new Baz();
    }

}

class Aze {
    private String toto ;
    private int titi ;
    private int tata ;

    public Aze(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.toto = "azertyu";
        this.titi = b;
        this.tata = c;
    }
}

class Baz extends Aze {        

    public Baz() {
        super(1,2,3);
    }
}
```

---

But the result doesn't contain any assembly code :

```
CompilerOracle: print *Test.main
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: printing of assembly code is enabled; turning on 
DebugNonSafepoints to gain additional output
loading Test
```

If I modify my main method by adding somme dummy code:

```
        long x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            x += i*i;
        }
        System.out.println("x=" + x);
```

It suddenly works and I get output wich is not only related to the added code.

For example I found assembly lines like this one:

```
0x026f1843: mov    $0x24655510,%edx   ;   {oop("azertyu")}
```

Now if I modify a bit the for loop using : `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)` I only have the result line `x=333283335000` but not assembly code at all.

**So I don't understand why I can't obtain the assembly code for all programs?**

*Note : I use the [hsdis-i386.dll](http://classparser.blogspot.fr/2010/03/hsdis-i386dll.html) linked in [Oracle wiki about PrintAssembly](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly)*

Comment: Note: GNU has a Java Compiler ("GCJ") that compiles Java "ahead-of-time" to native assembler. Haven't used it myself but maybe you're interested to try it. See https://gcc.gnu.org/java/

Comment: @geert3 Ok I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the "just-in-time-compiled" code is displayed, as that is the only thing that is assembler, the rest is interpreted byte code.

For the initial program, there was so little work to do that nothing was compiled, i.e. everything merely interpreted. The more loops and stuff you do in the program, the more will be compiled to assembler.

There is very little (no?) guarantee about what will be compiled and when.

The reason your "azertyu" is assembled might be because it is "invariant", and the optimizer found that out while running the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. That something I add in mind but I still find it weird. Especially the thing with the max index of the loop. Basically it could have been interpreted too because the result will never change. Also do you know anyway to "force" the compilation?

Comment: No I don't know how to "force" it, but one minimal requirement is to have a longer running program. Perhaps a `Thread.sleep(5000);` in the beginning will kick it off (haven't tried). Also often-executed or easily optimizable code may be compiled sooner, e.g. complex/long loops, small method-calls that can be inlined...